# VBC Error when trying to run automated build on VB project with TFS 2010

Tags: msbuild

[image]

Hey Guys,

I'm getting the error above when trying to run an automated build of one of our VB projects.
I've been through the build logs and can't find anything that suggests why it is failing.

It has been set up in the same way as our other automated builds but is the only VB.NET (v3.5) project I've set up so far. Anyone seen anything similar/had the same problem?

I've tried a bunch of different build configurations with no luck - just the error above and the message TF270015: 'MSBuild.exe' returned an unexpected exit code. Expected '0'; actual '1' after. Any help will be appreciated!

Edit: [Log File](http://www.mediafire.com/?v7l4flrytwf6o6r)

What is the correct strategy for debugging these automated build errors?
Should I log on to the build server and try build the solution in the workspace?

Comment: Can you post the Diagnostic output from a build and the related log file information?  Queue Build -> Parameter Tab -> Logging Verbosity -> Diagnostic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite a few issues with references.  If you take a look at the build log you will see them.  Do you have .Net 3.5 installed on the build machine?

> Dependency "Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35". (TaskId:16)
>         Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly
>   "Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35". Check to make sure the assembly
>   exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may
>   get compilation errors. (TaskId:16)

And

> Dependency "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerRuntime, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c". (TaskId:16)
>   Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly
>   "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerRuntime, Version=14.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c". Check to make sure

And

> Dependency "System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35". (TaskId:16)
>         Resolved file path is "C:\Program Files\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5\System.Web.Extensions.dll".
>   (TaskId:16)
>         Reference found at search path location
>   "{TargetFrameworkDirectory}". (TaskId:16)
>             For SearchPath "{TargetFrameworkDirectory}". (TaskId:16)
>             Considered "C:\Program Files\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5\System.Web.Extensions.exe", but it
>   didn't exist.
>   the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your
>   code, you may get compilation errors. (TaskId:16)

Comment: Thanks I'll double check those on Monday - The server definitely has .NET 3.5 installed. I was aware of the missing SharePoint dll reference but hadn't spotted the others. I'll add the Sharepoint one to the GAC (I can't install SharePoint on the server) and try figure out why it can't find the other references.